# os.walk raises "unknown exception" in Eclipse/PyDev when path is a windows mapped network drive

Tags: python, eclipse, search, pydev, os.walk

I am trying to write a module that searches for different files on mapped drives in a Windows environment. This works perfectly in PythonWin and Idle but raises an exception *"Unknown exception when splitting input. Press any key to quit"* when run in Eclipse/Pydev. 
L:\ i a mapped network drive

```
import os
path = "L:\\"
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
    print dirs
```

If I set  `path = "C:\\"` this works great.
Any ideas what differs Eclipse/PyDev from Idle?

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that I know PyDev does differently is a site customization... Try removing it just to see if it may fix things:

Rename:

`plugins\org.python.pydev_XXX\pysrc\pydev_sitecustomize\sitecustomize.py` to `__sitecustomize.py` and do the launch to see if that may be the issue...

Comment: No difference as far as I can see. Im not that well read on windows mapping theory :) but the script works then path = r"\\server.company.com\filearea\folder"